# Why href="#" is High Priority than onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick, href

I usualy found the following code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="func();return false">click</a>
```

but sometime my browser go to the top of the page?

Why `href="#"` is High Priority than onclick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't higher priority. The onclick fires and then the browser follows the link.

If you don't `return false` (note spelling) or `func` throws an error (thus not reaching the `return` statement) the event won't be canceled.

(As fallbacks for if the JS fails or is disabled go, however, a link to the top of the page is really sucky. [Progressive enhancement](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/) is the way forward.)

Comment: So the link should really be a link, unless the javascript does something else (for example, open a popup and then ignore the link). If it isn't a link, you should use another element that suits it's purpose better (a span for example).

Comment: If it opens a popup (which is shouldn't, since popups are a horrible user experience) then it should still be a link - the event should just cancel the default action.

Answer (score 1):

If the only reason you want to have a `href` value is to enable the hand cursor, you can use css style instead:

```
<a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="func();return false">click</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

...and a decade later, here's the answer to the question asked above;

```
<a href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault(); func()">click</a>
```

To save confusion, this answer does not address the "return false" aspect.  That subject can be researched separately.

PS; Technically there is no hierarchy (AKA "priority") for what happens when an Anchor Tag is clicked.  But since HREF is the "default" action / 
event for an anchor tag, from a certain perspective, HREF does "take priority" over OnClick.